# How can I find the length of a C string without using strlen?

Tags: c, string

If I want to know the length of the string without using **standard libraries** and the **array** in the program. How am I supposed to find the length?

Comment: Sounds like homework. If so, please add the [tag:homework] tag.

Comment: Start by reading what exactly a string is from a tutorial.

Comment: Sweet, this is homework! In that case, could you please do some assigned reading and then let us know what you think? Check out these notes for Chapter 5 of the K&R bible: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/krnotes/sx8.html.

Comment: Asking for answers on homework that can be done with simply doing the appropriate reading is the same as cheating.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate a C string until reaching to `\0`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_str_len(char *s)
{
  int len;
  char *ptr = s;
  for (len = 0; *ptr; ptr++, len++)
  // nothing
  ;
  return len;
}

int main()
{
  char str[] = "Hello";

  printf("%i\n", my_str_len(str));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Per [tag:homework], we try to avoid giving a complete answer to questions that are obviously homework problems.

Answer (score -1):

print that string using printf

int count = printf("%s", str);

printf returns the number of characters printed.

Comment: Hmm, technically you're right. But this answer is awful, sorry. Talk about having side-effects for an operation!

Comment: Last I checked, `printf()` was part of the standard library.